# You will get sick too

Tags: grammar

His mother has a sore throat.

He wanted to drink the coconut juice that her mother has been drink.

"You can't drink it. I have a sore throat." she said.

"I want to drink." he said.

> ***You will get sick too.***

sickness can be transmitted through water." mother told him.

Should I add "get" before sick? Is get used correctly here?

Comment: ...that **his** mother had been **drinking**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the proper term is "get sick." The phrase is used to describe someone becoming sick. "Become sick" is also acceptable, but is much more formal. Beyond the scope of your question, but possibly relevant to what you're writing: the phrase "be sick" can be taken to mean either "have an illness" or "vomit," depending on the context.